# twisted and print statement

Tags: python, logging, twisted

I wonder if I am using `print` statement with twisted in some asynchronous call, is this statement block event loop? Also I am interested in standart `logging` module usage with `logging.FileHandler` handler.

Comment: The `print` statement can block because it is writing to the standard output file descriptor.  I recommend asking your question about the logging module separately, stating previous research you have done.